# See whether object is undefined before executing script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently loading a `custom.js` file on my site and it calls various functions. However, to keep the size down I only load the libraries needed on certain pages.

Because of this, since the `custom.js` file is loaded on *every* page and it calls functions that the particular page may *not* have, I get `undefined is not a function` errors on my site on certain pages.

What I would like to be able to do is determine if something is defined before executing the code to keep the errors from popping up.

For an example, I'm using Jarallax (http://www.jarallax.com/) on my front page only with the following:

```
var jarallax = new Jarallax();
    jarallax.addAnimation('div#bigSlider',[{progress:'0%',marginTop:'0px'},{progress:'100%', marginTop:'-200px'}]);
```

Since Jarallax is only loaded on the homepage and no others I get the *undefined function* error on all pages but the hompeage. How could I first confirm Jarallax is loaded before attempting to execute the code?

Comment: `if (window.Jarallax) { // do something if it exists }` no good?

Comment: I like this simplicity of this solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since referring to undefined variables raises a `ReferenceError` exception, you could use a `try/catch` block to handle the exception.

```
try {
  var jarallax = new Jarallax();
} 
catch (e) {
  // desired behavior for this situation.
}
```

More on [try/catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) blocks.

Comment: Excellent! I didn't even think if try/catch :)

Answer (score 1):

> However, to keep the size down I only load the libraries needed on
>   certain pages. Because of this I get "undefined is not a function"
>   errors on my site on certain pages.

So this means you're not doing it properly on every page?

You could solve this by using a wrapper object or class:

```
(function($){

    var wrapper = {
        init: function(){
            var jarallax;

            if (typeof Jarallax == 'function'){
                jarallax = new Jarallax();
                jarallax.addAnimation('div#bigSlider',[{progress:'0%',marginTop:'0px'},{progress:'100%', marginTop:'-200px'}]);
            }
        }
    };

    // once the DOM is read
    $(function(){
        wrapper.init();
    });
}(window.jQuery));
```

By stalling the init function on the DOM ready, you can be certain the script is loaded if you make sure the script tag for Jarallax is added before the wrapper in the HTML. In any other case the init function won't do a thing.

Comment: It's a little contradiction to read "loaded on certain pages" -vs- "not working on certain pages". So I'm sensing "it works what I did" but not in every case. Retorical question to see if I understood correctly ^^

Comment: Ok, that makes sense that I didn't make sense ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof jarallax === "undefined") {
   var jarallax = {
   obj: {},

     return {
     obj;
   };
```